# Accessing property of javascript object returns undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to learn how to create JavaScript class in another .js file and access it from anywhere else. I have read a few examples, but can't seem to understand it completely.

For example, how do I access the following:

```js
//code in file2.js
getterTest = (function() {
  var _x = 15;

  return {
    doSomething: function() {
      _x += 5;
    },

    get x() {
      return _x;
    }
  }
});

//code in file1.js
console.log(getterTest._x); //undefined
console.log(getterTest.x); //should give 15
getterTest.doSomething();
console.log(getterTest.x); //should give 20
```

But it all gives `undefined` and the `.doSomething` method gives *not a function*.

I will go home now and read more about closure as @Liam suggested and will see what is going on tomorrow.

Comment: `getterTest` is a function, you'd have to call it first. Did you mean to use an IIFE?

Comment: This isn't a singleton. It's a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Comment: `console.log(getterTest().x);`

Comment: @Liam hmm, maybe I am in a mistake. I am going to read about closure.

Comment: @elclanrs I am not familiar with immediately-invoked function expression, but I will - this should give me an idea.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to create a [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in Javascript. There is no common context.

Comment: @Liam thanks for the missed ( ), now I get the 15, but the .doSomething still does not work.

Comment: add the `()` again to call the `getterTest` function `getterTest().doSomthing()`

Comment: @Liam ... not sure, but still, can you recommend any readings on how to achieve public accessible class methods without new Class()?

Comment: @MB did so, it got to it, but says 15 instead of 20 :(

Comment: created a fiddle for this,try here pelase https://jsfiddle.net/mp9tgq89/

Comment: @IgorGeorgiev see answer

Comment: @Wellwisher doesn't print anything on fiddle...

Comment: @MB Cheers, will try it tomorrow, cause I am going home

Comment: Don't edit the question to say it's solved. Marking an answer is enough. The question needs to remain to help others who may have a similar problem

Comment: @Liam sorry, did not know that. Should I edit it back, or should I have that in mind for the next time?

Comment: I've already fixed @Igor. Users with higher rep can edit other user posts. Just bear it in mind for next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok lets break this down

```
getterTest = (function() {});
```

`getterTest` is a function pointer. i.e. it is a variable that holds the **un-envoked** function.

If I do:

```
getterTest = (function() {});
getterTest();
```

I invoke the function.

If I do:

```
getterTest = (function() {});
var result = getterTest();
```

result contains the function returned from the getterTest function, i.e. an object (`{}`) that contains a function and a gettable x property

```
result = {
    doSomething: function() {
       _x += 5;
    },

    get x() {
        return _x;
    }
}
```

so I could do:

```
getterTest = (function() {});
var result = getterTest();
result.x;
```

### TL;DR

Really though; what you want is for `getterTest` to work like this:

```
getterTest = function() {
var _x = 15;

return {
    doSomething: function() {
       _x += 5;
    },

    get x() {
        return _x;
    }
}
}();
//invoke the function and store this in your variable by adding () above    

//code in file1.js
//console.log(getterTest._x);         //this is private so can't be accessed (you can only access things that are returned)
console.log(getterTest.x);         //should give 15
getterTest.doSomething();
console.log(getterTest.x);        //should give 20
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLcuu6uh/)

You cannot access _x outside of the closure, because it's scope is the function. This is , essentially, the point of closures. To keep things in scopes and to keep the "global context" clean.

---

### FYI

You might notice I kinda use "function" and "object" interchangeably in the above. People not used to Javascript find this odd but there is a good reason. In Javascript [a function is an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) o_O

Again this is one of the principals of what your trying to achieve here. It's all basically about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

Comment: That is very interesting :) I am used to code in AS3, and recently started with JS and all seems like a mess to me :D

Comment: JS is not a compiled language. It's built to be very flexible. This results in some weirdness if your not used to it. It is now [pretty much the most used language](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#technology) so get used to it :D

Comment: I am using it now, so I have to :D

Answer (score 0):

please do as,

```
//code in file2.js
getterTest = (function() {
    var _x = 15;
    return {
        doSomething: function() {
           _x += 5;
        },

        get x() {
            return _x;
        }
    }
}()); // added '()'


//code in file1.js
console.log(getterTest._x);         //undefined
console.log(getterTest.x);         //15
getterTest.doSomething();
console.log(getterTest.x);
```

Comment: You should highlight that you've added `()` and therefore invoked the method.

Comment: @Well Wisher I don't get it, seems the same. And yes, the console.log(getterTest._x) should be undefined for the sake of the test :)

Comment: @IgorGeorgiev i have added a () at the end.

Comment: @Wellwisher I see :) thanks, but now it says getterTest is not a function :D

Comment: still have problems, sorry :( Are you able to test it yourself?

Comment: whats the new prob please

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: getterTest is not a function

Comment: Why do you have a superfluous pair of parentheses around the function?

Answer (score -1):

you need to instantiate the class and then call the functions.

```
var g = getterTest(); 
console.log(g.x);         //15
g.doSomething();
console.log(g.x); //20
```

If you call `getterTest()` on each call, it will always get a new version of the class

```
console.log(getterTest().x);         //15
getterTest().doSomething();
console.log(getterTest().x); //15
```

I know this is not ideal for you. But this is the correct way to call the functions in `file2.js`
Other choice is to rewrite `file2.js`

Good luck!

Comment: This is not a class and does not need to be instantiated and calling `new` on it will not do what you think.

Comment: @torazaburo  see fix. removed the `new` keyword